# How to find maximum gap of observations for the whole duration of the time series.using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe like this,

```
date         value
2017-01-02  -0.665575
2017-01-02  2.850187
2017-01-03  6.035269
2017-01-03  -0.738031
2017-01-06  -0.330992
```

trying to find maximum gap of observations (maximum gap between the dates) for the whole duration of the time series.

I tried `pandas.rolling` window, I am not sure how to apply the method.

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by `gap`? On a time basis? All days are present

Comment: maximum gap between the dates

Comment: Between the dates? You have samples on each day

Comment: edited the question, removed two rows

Comment: df.date.diff().max()?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), which will give you the amount of days between samples, and take the `max`:

```
df.date.diff().max()
# Timedelta('3 days 00:00:00')
```

If you want the amount of days:

```
df.date.diff().max().days
# 3
```

If the dates are not in order start with `DataFrame.sort_values`:

```
df.sort_values('date').date.diff().max()
```

Comment: Why the downote, is there something wrong in the answer?

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did not down vote, i don't have enough reputations to do that.

Comment: Ah yes, it was addressed to the downvoter. You're welcome

Comment: `How to find the maximum number of observations in a 3-month
window for the duration of time series?
`

Comment: i think needs pd. rolling

Comment: You shouldn't do this. Now my answer does not answer your current question. I suggest you leave it as it was, and ask a new question

Comment: Otherwise give me some time and will add an update here, but leave question as it was please

Comment: ok you can edit my question, as it is understandable in future, I am sorry for editing

Comment: thank you for the solution, may i know what is happening in `df.date.dt.month//3`

Comment: my actual data has 3 columns, so I am getting this error, another column is string column `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Comment: can we do this using pd.rolling window instead of groupby ?

Comment: Can't check now, let me give it a look when I'm back at my laptop